# FFC connector with solder terminals on cable entry side

Tags: pcb, connector, surface-mount, fpc, ffc

Are there any FFC connectors that have all solder pins on the same side as the FFC slot (i.e. where the FFC cable is inserted).

I know in most situations / designs this wouldn't make any sense, but I have a very specific use case where I need this to reverse the direction of the FFC cable.

I'm specifically looking for a connector with 20 positions and 0.5mm pitch.

Imagine something like this mockup (or third option below with front flip)..

[image: mockup]
[image: comp]

Thanks!

Comment: that would also switch the order of pins

Comment: Switching the order of pins is not a concern and can be corrected by using an FFC cable with contacts on the same side (instead of opposite sides).

Comment: I see you added the mention of front flip, _after_ I answered your question. Is that just an example, or is it a requirement? I also see that, in your 3rd example, with the green check mark, the contacts are _under_ the body, not _in front_ of the body, as your text says. Which one of these two options do you want?

Comment: No, front flip is just an example. The first image is a mockup with back flip and the three images underneath are mockups with front flip. The requirement is 0.5mm pitch FFC connector with front or back flip and ALL (20) solder pins on the same side as the slot where the FFC cable is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Including (my site):

- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=PCA%200.3mm
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_slider_sockets&s=6260
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FH16%200.3%20mm
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FH18
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FH23
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FH29
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FH30%200.3%20mm
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FH36
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FB10
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FF02S
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=FH43B
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=6866
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=501912
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=Easy-on%20503566
- https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&s=XF3H
- 

ExtraDummyCharactersToSatisfyTheBot

Comment: Thank you for the multiple suggestions but unfortunately none of the connectors meet my requirements. They either only have half the solder pins on the same side or none (i.e Kyocera 6260 or Hirose FH18-27S-0.3).

Comment: I edited the original question to specify the pitch and number of pins.